# PHP/mySQL - using result from 'CONCAT' and 'AS' in 'LIKE' clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like, concatenation

Hi I have the following code;

```
if( ! empty( $post['search-bar'] ) ) {
    $search_data = preg_replace("#\s\s#is", '', preg_replace("#[^\w\d\s+]#is", '', $post['search-bar'] ) );
    $data_array = explode( " ", $search_data );
    $data_array = "'%" . implode( "%' OR '%", $data_array ) . "%'"; 
    $query =  "
SELECT CONCAT( PROFILE_PROFFESION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME) AS 'STRING'
FROM `" . ACCOUNT_TABLE . "` 
WHERE STRING LIKE ( " . $data_array . " ) 
  AND BUSINESS_POST_CODE LIKE '" . substr(P_BUSINESS_POST_CODE, 0, 4) . "%'";

    $q = mysql_query( $query, $CON ) or die( "_error_" . mysql_error() );   
    if( mysql_num_rows( $q ) != 0 ) {
        die();
    }
}
```

Problem is I want to use the temp col 'STRING' in the where clause but is returning 'unknown coloumn `STRING` Can any one point me in the right direction, regards Phil

I have printed out the query;

```
SELECT PROFILE_PROFFESION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME 
FROM nnn_accounts 
WHERE 
  CONCAT( PROFILE_PROFFESION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME) 
  LIKE ( '%web%' OR '%design%' ) 
AND BUSINESS_POST_CODE LIKE 'NG19%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap STRING in ` instead of '

Should be:
`` ..AS `STRING` ``

And then anywhere you refer to STRING should be `` `STRING` ``

**Edit: Here this should solve it:**

```
SELECT CONCAT( PROFILE_PROFFESION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME) AS `STRING`
FROM `" . ACCOUNT_TABLE . "` 
WHERE BUSINESS_POST_CODE LIKE '" . substr(P_BUSINESS_POST_CODE, 0, 4) . "%'"
HAVING `STRING` LIKE ( " . $data_array . " ) ;
```

Comment: still getting Unknown column 'STRING' in 'where clause'

Comment: Try using ``HAVING `STRING` LIKE ( " . $data_array . " )`` (Do this after the `WHERE` clause

Comment: thanks for the input. Im going to have to mark yours as correct due to my question, but does the same as Col. Shrapnel instructed. My problem being i am not getting correct results. how come `web` or `design` will return results but `web design` will not??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like you just can't use the temp col in the where clause 
just specify it as is:

```
WHERE CONCAT( PROFILE_PROFFESION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME) LIKE '%$data_array%')
```

Comment: I get no errors but getting no results. I have printed out the query;
SELECT PROFILE_PROFFESION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME FROM `nnn_accounts` WHERE CONCAT( PROFILE_PROFFESION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME) LIKE ( '%web%' OR '%design%' ) AND BUSINESS_POST_CODE LIKE 'NG19%'

Comment: if i enter `web` i get results. if i type in `design` i get results but `web design` gets no results.

Comment: your use of LIKE clause is just ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `'STRING'`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that was more suitable was

```
SELECT CONCAT( PROFILE_PROFFESION, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME) AS `STRING` FROM `tablename` WHERE BUSINESS_POST_CODE LIKE 'NG19%' HAVING `STRING` LIKE '%web%' OR `STRING` LIKE '%design%'
```