# search in myadmin database by two columns using like

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

In my database i have one column for first name and last name.
In my code i have combined this two columns and used it as full name.
i have one search box in the display which looks like this,

[image]

the code for the searching is like,

switch($search_by){

```
    case "fullname":
        $sql_where_clause = "fname like '".$search_keyword."%';
        break;
    case "user_name":
        $sql_where_clause = "uname like '".$search_keyword."%';
        break;
    }
```

and this $sql_where_clause is used in the query for searching.

when i search for full name as arpi which is my first name in database it gives me perfect answer because i have done code for first name.
but the problem is, when i search as arpi patel where arpi is first name and patel is last name then search is not performed because i have not done code for that because i don't know how to perform this.

does anyone know how to fire query for my first and last name columns together in the $sql_where_clause

Comment: Try `fname + lname like...` in your where clause

Comment: Also you can use concat() function ... Check This -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672817/php-mysql-using-result-from-concat-and-as-in-like-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use logical operatores in your SQL query like this:
`$sql_where_clause = "fname LIKE '$fname' AND uname LIKE '$uname'";`

How can you get $fname and $uname variables? If your $search_keyword looks like this:
`family name` you can explode it by space `$search_parts = explode(' ', $search_keyword, 2)`. But in that case you do not know which part is the family and which is the name, so you have to perform query like that:
`$sql_where_clause = "(fname LIKE '${part[0]}' AND uname LIKE '${part[1]}') OR (fname LIKE '${part[1]}' AND uname LIKE '${part[0]}')";`

Btw, don't forget to sanitize your queries against sql-injections. Bad way - use mysql_real_escape_string. Good and easy way - use PDO and prepaired queries.